# Install specific HWE kernel

Tags: 20.04, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

With Ubuntu 20.04, I know that we can install the latest HWE kernel via `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. At the moment, this installs linux-hwe-5.13. However, the drivers for the hardware I am working with only currently support linux-hwe-5.11. How would I go about installing this specific kernel?

Thanks

EDIT: After running the proposed fix by N0rbert

output of `ls /boot` is

```
config-5.4.0-050400-generic  initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic              System.map-5.11.0-46-generic     vmlinuz-5.4.0-050400-generic
config-5.4.0-73-generic      initrd.img-5.4.0-050400-generic           System.map-5.4.0-050400-generic  vmlinuz-5.4.0-73-generic
config-5.4.0-96-generic      initrd.img-5.4.0-050400-generic.old-dkms  System.map-5.4.0-73-generic      vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic
efi                          initrd.img-5.4.0-73-generic               System.map-5.4.0-96-generic
```

And output of `dpkg -S '/boot/vmlin*' is:

```
linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-73-generic
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-050400-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-050400-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic
linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Please add output of `ls /boot` and `dpkg -S '/boot/vmlin*'` to the question by editing it.

Comment: Done -- it looks like the 5.11.0-46 kernel was successfully installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this two steps way:

```
# remove 5.13
sudo apt-get autopurge 'linux-image-5.13.0-*-generic' \
'linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-*-generic' 'linux-modules-5.13.0-*-generic' \
'linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-*' linux-generic-hwe-20.04

# install latest 5.11
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.11.0-46-generic \
linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic \
linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-46-generic linux-tools-5.11.0-46-generic \
linux-hwe-5.11-tools-common
```

It is strange that there is no binary meta-package for 5.11 kernel, so latest version may be determined in future by visiting relevant page of source package at https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/linux-hwe-5.11 or by using the following one-liner below:
`apt-cache search 'linux-image-5.11.*generic' --names-only | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | grep --only-matching -E "5.11.[0-9]-[0-9]{2,3}"`

Comment: Hey -- thanks for your answer! I tried out the proposed solution, and, unfortunately, the system didn't recognize the kernel as having a HWE stack (via `hwe-support-status --verbose`). (I additionally installed `linux-hwe-5.11-tools-common`).

Comment: I again tested the system after the proposed solution, and the drivers / hardware are working fine -- I had messed up a driver install. However, it still does not appear to be a hwe kernel (via `hwe-support-status --verbose`) maybe because it is not the current hwe kernel for the OS?

Comment: Simply ignore output of `hwe-support-status` in this case, it is not perfect. Or better - report bug to launchpad by `apport-bug update-manager-core` about this problem.